# Broken Logic? - ascending and descending order of letters

Tags: java

I have wrote some code which reads in a word and displays if the letters are in ascending order or not in ascending order, Ignoring letter case in my comparison. However after inputting the following letters, there are two errors which are marked with a '<'.

```
abcdefgh   letters in ascending order 
Xabcdefg   letters in ascending order       <<<<<<<<<<
aXbcdefg   letters not in ascending order 
abXcdefg   letters not in ascending order 
abcXdefg   letters not in ascending order 
abcdXefg   letters not in ascending order 
abcdeXfg   letters not in ascending order 
abcdefXg   letters not in ascending order 
abcdefgX   letters not in ascending order  <<<<<<<<<<
ABCDEFGH   letters in ascending order
```

"Xabcdefg" is clearly not in ascending order and "abcdefgX", the opposite, so why does my code output false information for these two specific lines. Please could anyone review my code below and help me sort this out. I am using BlueJ to code, and am 4 months in learning Java from scratch so i may need a hand with this and an explanation with any answers. Thank you.

```
 public class Main
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String word = BIO.getString();
    while (!word.equals( "END" ) )
      {
        boolean inorder = false;
        // Convert the above string to a char array.
        char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
        { //Check pair
            if ( arr[i] > arr[i+1] ) 
            { 

                System.out.printf("%-10s letters not in ascending order ", word);
                inorder = true;

            }
        }
        if ( ! inorder )
        { 
            System.out.printf("%-10s letters in ascending order ", word);

        }
        word = BIO.getString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim that you did a case insensitive comparison of the characters, but in reality you did not.  Try doing a bona fide case insensitive comparison in your loop, and the code should produce the expected output:

```
String word = BIO.getString();
while (!word.equals( "END" )) {
    char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
    inorder = true;
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        char a = Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]);       // convert both characters
        char b = Character.toLowerCase(arr[i+1]);     // to lowercase
        if (a > b) {
            inorder = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (inorder) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s letters in ascending order ", word);
    }
    else {
        System.out.printf("%-10s letters not in ascending order ", word);
    }
    word = BIO.getString();
}
```

By the way, the reason that the following string:

```
Xabcdefg
```

appears to be in order is that technically it *is* in order with regard to the order of the ASCII characters.  Capital letters appear in the ASCII table *before* lowercase letters, so `X` comes even before lowercase `a`.  But by making everything lowercase, we eliminate this problem.

Comment: it now outputs, "abcdefgh   letters in ascending order abcdefgh", the input is now followed right after the statement of whether the word is in ascending or descending order.

Comment: @JonathanKelsey I refactored the code slightly, have a look.

Comment: If you run the code with your refactored code, upon inputting a string into the console, it provides a never ending answer loop. I have to ctrl-w the console and reset the JVM.

Comment: I assumed that you figured out that I did not post your entire code, only the part having the problem.  I have added more code, hopefully now it is clear how to assimilate that to what you already have.

Comment: Thank you very much, your help has been invaluable :) Happy new Year! 

Answer (score 0):

Java is a case sensitive language.

X is uppercase which comes before a lowercase letter.

Change the > line

```
arr[i] > arr[i+1]
```

to

```
arr[i].toUpperCase() > arr[i+1].toUpperCase()
```